# Switching ctrl-c to win-c in console

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, usability

I would like to switch, in terminal, key combinations with control to combinations with win key so e.g. ctrl+c becomes win+c, ctrl+d becomes win+d. Then I would like to set ctrl+c/v for copy and paste. Is there a terminal emulator or shell configuration options that allows this?

Answer (score 0):

which terminal emulator are you using? which Linux distro? After you get that you can check the short cuts of the system/terminal emulator.

Comment: I can use any terminal emulator that support switching these keys.